# Processing - void needs to execute on keyPressed but does not delay

Tags: key, processing, delay, pressed

I am working on a processing file, it works as a karaoke system. 
The karaoke itself is a movie. It also works with points.

Before the game starts. I want to display a picture.
When any key is pressed and then released a list of actions need to start from there.
I tried with a if keyPressed function, but the movie (with music) seems to play from the beginning.
It is only working when you hold on to the key. I want it to work when the random key is released.

The part that needs to display before the game starts is:

```
image(beginscherm, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
```

The part that needs to work after releasing a key  is from:

```
image(mov, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
```

Who's here to help me out..

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import processing.video.*;
Movie mov;

Minim minim;
AudioInput input;
int inputNiveau;

float scoreH = 600;

boolean fotomaken = true;
Capture cam;
int x = 0;
PImage beginscherm;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  mov = new Movie(this, "karaoke_4.mp4");
  mov.play();
  cam = new Capture(this, 320, 180, 30);
  cam.start();
  textSize(28);

  minim = new Minim (this);
  input = minim.getLineIn (Minim.STEREO, 512); 

  beginscherm = loadImage("beginscherm.jpg"); 
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void draw() {
  image(beginscherm, 0, 0, 1280, 720);

  image(mov, 0, 0, 1280, 720);

  if (cam.available()) {
      cam.read();
  }
  if ((scoreH >= 448.98) && (scoreH <= 451.00)){
    pushMatrix();
    scale(-1,1);
    image(cam, -320, 0);
    popMatrix();
  }
  if ((scoreH >= 449.99) && (scoreH <= 450.00) && (fotomaken == true)){
    saveFrame("images/sing-##.png");
    fotomaken = false;
  }

  inputNiveau = int(input.mix.level()*800);
  fill(137,197,255,127);
  text(inputNiveau, 800, 700);
  rect(900, 680, inputNiveau, 20);
  scoreH = constrain(scoreH, 0, 600);
  scoreH = constrain(scoreH, 0, 580);

  noStroke();
  fill(49,127,203);
  rect(1090,61,85,605,100);
  fill(137,197,255,127);
  rect(1090,61,85,scoreH,100,100,0,0);

  rotate(0.2);
  fill(252,209,22);
  rect(1070,-210,150,57);
  fill(0,56,147);
  rect(1070,-154,150,28);
  fill(206,17,38);
  rect(1070,-126,150,28);

  if(inputNiveau >= 0 && inputNiveau <= 150){
  scoreH = scoreH - 0.02; 
  }      
  if(inputNiveau >= 150 && inputNiveau <= 500){
  scoreH = scoreH - 0.06; 
  }      
  if(inputNiveau >= 500 && inputNiveau <= 900){
  scoreH = scoreH - 0.16; 
  }
  if(inputNiveau >= 900 && inputNiveau <= 1000){
  scoreH = scoreH - 0.5; 
  }
  println(scoreH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common solution is to provide **state variable** and make `draw()` method to draw according to current state.

Try something like this:

```
int STATE_BEFORE = 1;
int STATE_AFTER = 2;

int state = STATE_BEFORE;

draw() {

  if (state == STATE_BEFORE) {
    drawBefore();
  }
  else if (state == STATE_AFTER) {
    drawAfer()
  }
  else if ...

}

void drawBefore() {
  image(beginscherm, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
  ...
}

void drawAfter() {
  image(mov, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
  ...
}

void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  char key = e.getKeyChar();
  int code = e.getKeyCode();

  if (key == ' ') {
    changeState( STATE_AFTER );
  }
}

void changeState(int newState) {
  if (state == STATE_BEFORE) {
     // actions when leaving this state
  }
  if (state == STATE_AFTER) {
    // actions when leaving this state
  }

  state = newState;
}
```

As you can see - some actions (for example keyPressed) can change **current state**.
And `draw()` method draws only what depends on state.

You can of course introduce more states (STATE_X, STATE_Y, etc) and more complicated actions done when state is changing...

You can see my past answer on introducing state to simplify `draw()` method:
[Run Code Inside One Thread In Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202449/run-code-inside-one-thread-in-another/27203360#27203360)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two states you can use `boolean` variable that define if key was released and video is running or not. Initialize some global variable:

```
boolean kye_released = false;
```

Also you video start from begging because you started it inside `setup`. You need to move `mov.play()` to `keyReleased()` event handle function.

```
void keyReleased(){
  kye_released = true;  
  theMov.play();  
}
```

Last think you need to do is separate them inside `draw()`:

```
void draw() {
  if(kye_released){    
    image(mov, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
  else{
    image(beginscherm, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
  }
  ...
```